# PHP - Accessing variables dynamically

Tags: php

Is there a way, in PHP, to change which variable is being changed based on another factor. Example:

```
$str1 = "The string is 1";
$str2 = "The string is 2";
$str3 = "The string is 3";
$X = 3;
echo $strX;

>> "The string is 3."
```

Edit: Thanks that's exactly what I needed :)

Comment: [Variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php): `echo ${"str".$X};`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?php
$str1 = "The string is 1";
$str2 = "The string is 2";
$str3 = "The string is 3";
$X = 3;
echo ${"str".$X};
?>
```

read more here [Variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

Comment: Little explanation will help to future visitors.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for

```
  $str1 = "The string is 1";
  $str2 = "The string is 2";
  $str3 = "The string is 3";
  $X = "str2";
  echo ${$X};
```

You could also use

```
   $str1 = "The string is 1";
   $str2 = "The string is 2";
   $str3 = "The string is 3";
   $X = "2";
   echo ${"str".$X};
```